# PIP installation confusion Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip, installation

I installed python 3.5.2 and did some coding fine . I then tried to download a module and was told that i need pip. I searched to see if i have it on disc and i actually have a file called "scripts" with different versions of pip in it.
pip, pip3 , pip3.5.

I double clicked on pip3.5, i got a black box some writing and it disappeared but pip was not installed.

Can someone please tell me what to do because on the net the instructions are confusing..you would be surprised.

Please take me by the hand and step by step if you can assume i know nothing.

I downloaded numpy.rar and it's on my desktop.

So, I got module and various pip.exe files....what next?

Comment: numpy rar has multiple files in it plus a setup file....they are all as a rar file on my dektop. do i have to copy them to a directory?...

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks yeah, i dont suppose you can help me with this:

Comment: I am trying to lock a .py application. I thought to create a password for it but the program can be opened with ide.  I was thinking about using something called file lock but as i am a newbie i dont know how it works. do you create a filelock.py code to file lock another .py program?? cheers man

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark as it. For the new problem, if you want contact me or ask a new question with more details :)

Comment: i dont have a high enuff reputation to mark it...it wont let me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run pip with double click on it, but you need to launch it from command line.

The basic pip command are:

```
pip install <package name>
pip freeze
pip list
```

The first one installs new package, and the second and the third are used to check which package and which version are installed on you pc.

Now, if you want install numpy on your pc, that I suppose is a windows machine, it's not always simple.

To avoid this, I suggest to download from this [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) the numpy.whl for you enviroment.

After this open the command line directly in the Python 3.5 Scripts folder in this way:

Navigate in the directory Scripts, keep pressed the maiusc key and right click; you should see the option **Open command windows here**. Click on it.

Now you should have opened a command line in the Scripts folder.

Alternatively, you can navigate in your directory with the command 
**cd 'directory_path'**.

Now install numpy with the following command:

```
pip install file_name_dowloaded_before
```

for example, if your downloaded file (numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl) is in on desktop you can type:

```
pip install Desktop\path\numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

After this you can check if numpy is correctly installed with **pip freeze** command.

Let me know